# Override the default format for some legend items in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Wanting to use ChartJS to generate a complex combination graph. All working well with the exception of being able to control the formatting of the legend.

Trying to achieve something like this:
[desired chart display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPIGU.png)

The code I have for this is below. Have tried using the generateLabels function to override but with no success. I'd settle for being able to set the background color of the boxes in the legend to be clear so that the dashed lines are more obvious.

```js
# quickchart-python https://github.com/typpo/quickchart-python

from quickchart import QuickChart

qc = QuickChart()
qc.width = 600
qc.height = 400

# Config can be set as a string or as a nested dict
qc.config = """{
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    "labels": [
"2015-16",
"2016-17",
"2017-18",
"2018-19",
"2019-20",
"2020-21",
"2021-22",
"2022-23",
"2023-24",
"2024-25",
"2025-26",
"2026-27",
"2027-28",
"2028-29",
"2029-30",
"2030-31",
"2031-32",
"2032-33",
"2033-34",
"2034-35",
"2035-36",
"2036-37",
"2037-38",
"2038-39",
"2039-40",
"2040-41",
"2041-42",
"2042-43",
"2043-44",
"2044-45",
"2045-46",
"2046-47",
"2047-48",
"2048-49"
    ],
    "datasets": [
      {
        "label": "Emissions (actual)",
        "borderColor": "rgb(192,0,0)",
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(192,0,0)",
        "pointBorderWidth": 0,
        "pointBackgroundColor": "rgb(192,0,0)",
        "pointStyle":"line",
        "pointRadius": 0,
        "fill": false,
        "data": [
2250,2230,2195,2185,2170,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
        ],
        "yAxisID": "y"
      },
      {
        "label": "Emissions (projected)",
        "borderColor": "rgb(192,0,0)",
        "borderDash": [4,4],
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "pointBorderWidth": 0,
        "pointBackgroundColor": "rgb(192,0,0)",
        "pointStyle":"line",
        "pointRadius": 0,
        "fill": false,
        "data": [
,,,,2170,2170,2170,2170,2170,2190,2200,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,
2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210,2210
        ],
        "yAxisID": "y"
      },
      {
        "label": "Sequestration (estimated)",
        "borderColor": "rgb(0,112,192)",
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,112,192)",
        "pointBorderWidth": 2 ,
        "pointBackgroundColor": "rgb(0,112,192)",
        "pointStyle":"line",
        "pointRadius": 0,
        "fill": false,
        "data": [
3197,3159,3121,3083,3008,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
        ],
        "yAxisID": "y"
      },
      {
        "label": "Sequestration (projected)",
        "borderColor": "rgb(0,112,192)",
        "borderDash": [4,4],
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,112,192)",
        "pointBorderWidth": 2,
        "pointBackgroundColor": "rgba(0,112,192,0.1)",
        "pointStyle":"line",
        "pointRadius": 0,
        "fill": false,
        "data": [
,,,,3008,2970,2932,2894,2856,2818,2780,2742,2704,2666,2628,2590,2552,
2514,2476,2438,2400,2362,2324,2286,2248,2210,2172,2134,2096,2058,2020,
1982,1944,1906
],
        "yAxisID": "y"
      },
      {
        "label": "Cumulative balance (actual)",
        "borderColor": "rgb(112,173,71)",
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(112,173,71)",
        "pointBorderWidth": 0,
        "pointBackgroundColor": "rgb(112,173,71)",
        "pointStyle":"line",
        "pointRadius": 0,
        "fill": true,
        "data": [
947,1876,2802,3700,4538,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
        ],
        "yAxisID": "y1"
      },
      {
        "label": "Cumulative balance (projected)",
        "borderColor": "rgba(112,173,71,0.4)",
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(112,173,71,0.6)",
        "pointBorderWidth": 0,
        "pointBackgroundColor": "rgba(112,173,71,0.6)",
        "pointStyle":"line",
        "pointRadius": 0,
        "fill": true,
        "data": [
,,,,4538,5338,6100,6824,7510,8138,8718,9250,9744,10200,10618,10998,11340,11644,
11910,12138,12328,12480,12594,12670,12708,12708,12670,12594,12480,12328,12138,
11910,11644,11340
        ],
        "yAxisID": "y1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {
    "stacked": false,
    "legend" : { 
      display: true,  
      position: 'bottom',
      generateLabels(chart) {
        return {
          fillStyle: "rgb(255,255,255)"
          }
        
        
        }
    },
    "title": {
      "display": false,
      "text": "Chart.js Line Chart - Multi Axis"
    },
    "scales": {
      "xAxes":[{ 
        "ticks": {"fontFamily": "Calibri",
            "fontSize": 9}
      }],
      "yAxes": [
      {
        "id": "y",
        "type": "linear",
        "display": true,
        "position": "left",
        "ticks": {
            "min": 1000,
            "max": 3500,
            "stepSize": 500,
            "fontFamily": "Calibri",
            "fontSize": 9
            },
          "scaleLabel": {
            "display": true,
            "labelString": "Emissions and Sequestration - tCO2e per year",
            "fontFamily": "Calibri",
            "fontSize": 11
            }
      }, 
      {
        "id": "y1",
        "type": "linear",
        "display": true,
        "position": "right",
        "gridLines": {
          "drawOnChartArea": false
        },
        "ticks": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 14000,
            "stepSize": 2000,
            "fontFamily": "Calibri",
            "fontSize": 9
            },
          "scaleLabel": {
            "display": true,
            "labelString": "Cumulative carbon balance - tCO2e",
            "fontFamily": "Calibri",
            "fontSize": 11
            }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}"""

# You can get the chart URL...
print(qc.get_url())

# Get the image as a variable...
image = qc.get_image()

# Or write the chart to a file
qc.to_file('mychart.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you putted the `generateLabels` function in the root of the legend options while it needs to be nested within the `labels` key like so:

```js
options: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      generateLabels: (chart) => {
        // Implementation
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration

Comment: Thanks. That has made a difference, but I'm struggling to understand the structure of what needs to be returned from the generateLabels function such that I can have different attributes for the different labels in the legend. The link provided gives me some of the attributes, but I haven't been able to work out the structure.

Comment: Update - have managed to work it out. I've used a brute force approach at the moment by simply returning an array of formatting definitions (array has 6 elements, one for each of the labels, and so can differentiate the formatting for each record).

Comment: You need to return an array of objects, where each object is 1 legend item. And the interface for the objects which you can co figure can be found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface